# Spaceships named Adam and Eve calling a third named God

Tags: story-identification, ray-bradbury

Looking for a story my father told me about when I was a kid. 3 spaceships traveling and 2 of them had to land for repairs. The mothership left and had them send a signal so they could return to get them later. When you shortened the names of the two who landed, it came out as Adam and Eve and the mothership (Godin?) came out to be God. And it explained prayer (signal) Adam and Eve etc. sound familiar to anyone??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaggy_God_story

Comment: There are literally hundreds of examples of this trope; http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/adam_and_eve

Comment: No one here knows who you or your father are, so "from my father's era" is completely meaningless.  Do you think you could give an actual year or year range instead?